# Mozilla firefox version 64: Kepress event called for keys like tab, backspace , arrowkeys etc

Tags: javascript, angular

```
     @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    let isValidExp = true;
    if (!this.expression.test(key)) {
      isValidExp = false;
    }
    return isValidExp;
  }
```

Above piece of snippet calls for the keys like backspace, arrowkeys etc. Resulting it is returning false and keys are not working as expected. This is happening in Mozilla Firefox (version 64) Windows 8.1
I know i can have set of keycodes and based on that i can return true. But can someone help me with this issue to be more generic solution to avoid all these kind of scenarios. Kindly help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "keys are not working as expected"?

Comment: @BrettGregson I meant, if i hit backspace, it does nothing. If i hit delete, nothing happens, Only with this browser version (64). Why it dont work, because my regex will fail. As in other browsers( latest version) including mozilla. Key press event does not fire on hitting  backspace or delete keys. I hope this helps.